# Cannot download s3 image stored with Paperclip (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am able to upload images using Paperclip, and can see them in my bucket on Amazon's S3 management console website, but the url provided by Paperclip (e.g., image.url(:thumb)) cannot be used to access the image.  I get a url that looks something like this:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx/images/000/000/012/thumb/image.jpg?1366900621

When i put that URL in my browser, I'm sent to an XML page that states:  "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint."

where the "endpoint" is a subdomain of Paperclip path.  But when I go to that "endpoint", I just get another error that says "Access Denied".  According to the file information provided by the Amazon site, however, the image is publicly viewable.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My development.rb file simply contains the following:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => AWS_BUCKET,
      :access_key_id => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      :secret_access_key => AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by changing the default for :url

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb 
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

I'm in the domestic U.S., but it appears that this was still necessary for my code to work (cf. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)